# Inser Ignore into table is not working

Tags: mysql

```
insert ignore table ( field2 , name) Values ( 22 , 'value3');
```

its adding duplicating the value

and table strcture :

```
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID                     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| field2                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| field2                 | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name                   | varchar(90)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

out put

```
1  22 2 value2
2  22 2 value2
3  23 2 value3
```

Comment: @Alan Haggai Alavi: how are  you Alan Haggai Alavi ? you haven't be around long time .. i have seen after one year ..

Comment: Fine, thanks. Been a bit busy with life.

Comment: Why was this tagged "perl"? It has nothing to do with Perl at all. I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an index on one of the fields that  you are inserting? If not, add one.

Answer (score 1):

You need a unique index on field2  if you don't want duplicates of field2. INSERT IGNORE ignores the insert if there's an error, without any unique index or constraint on those fields, there will be no errors

If you don't  want duplicates on the combination of field2 and name , you'll need a unique index on (field2,name).